# Are there bounds or measurements on the derivative of acceleration (jerk)

Tags: general-relativity, kinematics, acceleration

The title says it all. Is there a physical maximum value to the 3rd derivative of position?

Common Lore says that there is not and that jerk does not play any role in physics. My guess is that there is not as well. But my question is looking to stir the pot a bit. Have there been experiments on this? Has anyone tried to detect perturbations to Newtonian kinematics when high values of the 3rd derivative are involved?